# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I want to download CSV file from URL. For that i am using HTTP URL Connection. 
 While running the code, i am getting below error:

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://twc.centercode.com/files/report.aspx/PLS Tracker.csv?t=GetElementFullCSV&r=0668821a036046ef9fde587c609e2c8f&e=47437d179bce477f936dcfdc470bf378
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Please find below code:

```
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;  
        String fileURL = "https://twc.centercode.com/files/report.aspx/PLS Tracker.csv?t=GetElementFullCSV&r=0668821a036046ef9fde587c609e2c8f&e=47437d179bce477f936dcfdc470bf378";  
        String fileName = "EFTReportTest.csv";  
        String saveDir = "D:\\";  
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);  
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        String saveFilePath = saveDir + "" + fileName;
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();

        System.out.println("File downloaded");
      }
         else{
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Your URL may unreachable, please check it

Comment: @TuyenNguyen - when i am hitting the URL directly on Chrome Browser, it is downloading the file.

Comment: I also tested, but the HttpURLConnection can not open this URL to it through the exception. You should check the correct type of URL to using with HttpURLConnection

Comment: Also check if there is a problem with security of the URL, you using https it may have some setting else?

Comment: Maybe the server checks User-Agent, Accept or any other header.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen - solved the above error by fixing the space issue in URL. But now while running the code, file is not getting downloaded at the desired location. Can you help on that?

Comment: @Nikhil - "file is not getting downloaded at the desired location" what is it means? The file is not download? or file downloaded but not in your indicated location?

Answer (score 0):

HTML code 400 is "Bad request" [(See here)](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Basically, what you're sending to the server is invalid or not formatted in the way it's expecting. This could be due to user agent, security, etc. I don't know enough about the website in question to tell you how they expect it, you might want to check the site for any information about an API or likewise that you could use.